# How is Complex number assignment from a double enabled?

Tags: c#

The Complex structure in System.Numerics allows assignment like this

```
Complex c = 3.72;
```

If I wanted to make my own Complex struct, how would I program this capability? I like it better than using constructors as in

```
Complex c = new Complex(3.72);
```

Comment: Since you've likely read [Complex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation already and found how it is done... Can you please clarify what type of help you are looking here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare an [implicit conversion operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Code-Apprentice for the correct answer. I will just post exactly the code I added to my Complex struct

```
    public static implicit operator Complex(double x)
    {
        return new Complex(x);  // implicit conversion
    }
```

This seems to work.

I will clarify why I am doing this. I wrote a large modeling code using Microsoft Complex everywhere. I tried to use the code in a Xamarin forms project but I could not get a reference to System.Numerics. To make progress I had to resurrect an old Complex struct I had made years ago, and get it to match the Microsoft capabilities.